# Klein RT210 GFCI tester not triggering AFCI breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, afci

My question is should a GGCI tester work on AFCI breaker?

Background:
I have a [KLEIN RT210 tester](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/electrical-testers/gfci-outlet-tester) with an [Eaton AFCI breaker](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/eaton-15-amp-single-pole-arc-fault-breaker/1000160153) and when test a plug the lights tell me that it is wired correctly, however, "PUSH TO CHECK GFCI" does not trip the breaker.

Looking online people are saying that the breaker is wired wrong, however with the wiring coming back as correct on the tester is confusing me.

Comment: Why would you expect a Ground Fault tester to trip an Arc fault breaker?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore that is my question, I am not sure.  I want to make sure I don't have a problem.

Comment: [Klein RT310 **AFCI** /GFCI Outlet Tester](https://www.kleintools.com/catalog/electrical-testers/afci-gfci-outlet-tester) is what you need. Testing at the breaker is fine but I would feel more comfortable testing it in the real space where arcs happen; away from the breaker.

Comment: On a dry (low humidity) day, you can wear socks, shuffle your feet across the carpet and plug the tester in. You'll probably have enough static build up to get a good spark that should cause the GFCI tester to emit enough static to trip the AFCI breaker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  It should not.  AFCI is designed to trip when the waveform changes to indicate arcing.  It is primarily to protect against fire hazards from sparks.

GFCI is designed to detect leakage to ground (e.g. through a human to a metal sink.)  It works by detecting current differences between hot and neutral.

A GFCI tester works by connecting a small amount of current, through a resistor to ground.  This simulates a ground fault, and should trip a GFCI breaker or outlet.

A GFCI tester does not simulate arcing, and will not trip an AFCI breaker.

However, there may be a test button on the breaker itself.

Comment: There is a tester on the breaker and that works!  Thanks

Comment: I have to wonder if AFCI test buttons actually create arcs

Comment: Probably not.  I'd guess that it would simulate whatever waveform the AFCI is trying to detect.

Answer (score 5):

GFCI = Ground Fault Detector
AFCI = Arc Fault detector

Your Eaton AFCI breaker includes GFPE protection.  GFPE is a weak form of GFCI, which senses at 30 milliamps instead of 5 milliamps. This is not good enough for human-safety protection, but is good enough for detecting two types of arc faults.

(hot-ground and neutral-ground parallel arc faults *are also* ground faults, you see).

Most of those GFCI testers are designed to effectively test GFCIs, so they only create about a 6-10 milliamp ground fault.  That is below the detection threshold of the GFPE.

Why not just make *all* GFCIs and GFPEs super sensitive down to 5mA? Because then you get nuisance trips.

Comment: For us Europeans 30mA is considered good enough for human safety, lower is allowed but not required (and not generally available)

Comment: @Pelle What makes you think that?  The 30mA threshold in Europe is for a bunch of reasons and human safety took a back seat.  First was detecting L-E and N-E (H-G and N-G) arc-faults (same thing we use it for).  Second was assuring 1 device could protect the whole house, to keep costs down. With a whole house worth of wiring, you need a higher 30mA threshold or you'll get nuisance trips.  That whole house requirement painted them into a corner.  But it was the only way to get it done in 1970 or whenever they legislated it.

Comment: But the whole house requirement has long gone, right now I am required to install at least 2 GFCI per house, and no more then 4 circuits per GFCI. But still the 30mA has remained. So it may nog be not be the best, but somehow it is good enough

Comment: @Pelle GFCI is not the correct word for those.  Those are GFPE.  Or in British parlance, RCD.  Every country makes compromises on safety based on dealing with the installed base they are stuck with, if you have any doubts of that, look at USA plugs, UK ring mains, German lack of polarization or USA's 120/240 split-phase (a leftover from Edison's DC, where it did make sense).